# asp.net Images (not in Images folder) are hidden by embedded style

Tags: css, asp.net, image

I have an issue with any images (not stored in the "/Images" folder). My application is adding style rules to hide the image automatically. Here's the output html:

```
<img id="MainContent_OrderAdsFormView_AdImagePreview" class="img-responsive" src="../Images/Ads/Stock/slide_01.jpg" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;">
```

Here's the server control:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="AdImagePreview" ImageUrl="~/Images/Ads/Stock/slide_01.jpg" CssClass="img-responsive" Visible="true" />
```

As you can see even setting visibility to true did not help. I have no problem with displaying any images in the Images folder but not the sub-directories. I have to have sub-directories under Images folder. I can't just move all picture to Images folder. I have not permission issue as I can open the image url directly in the browser. It's this stupid styling rules. I do not know where they come from. Why my application is adding this style rule and how to stop it! Please help, I am really stuck!

Comment: Sounds like you're maybe using some javascript? (class="img-responsive")... The code you've shown is ok and can't be a source of this problem, so it's definitely something you somewhat 'forgot' to tell us. Or maybe some aggressive browser plugin is in charge like meda suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using chrome or something like that?

You probably have `Adblocker` plugin install looking to remove  anything starting with `Ad`.

Since you called it `AdImagePreview` it will add css to remove it from the page.

Comment: Thanks Meda and Walther. It was the adblocker. I changed the image and sub-directory name and it works now. I really appreciate it! I lost one day of work trying to figure out what is going on.